# Changing \leftmark number to \oldstylenums in memoir

Tags: sectioning, formatting, header-footer, memoir, oldstylenums

Referring to the image below, I am trying to change the number '1' on the `\leftmark` header to `\oldstylenums` number format. Can anyone help?

[image: Images]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase\leftmark}}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

I've attempted to copy and paste the default code provided by `memoir` (referring to the code below) hoping that I could change it from there, but it ended up with multiple errors of which I don't understand.

```
\makepagestyle{headings}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
 \def\chaptermark##1{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
   \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
     \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
    \fi
   \fi
   ##1}}{}}%
 \def\sectionmark##1{%
  \markright{\MakeUppercase{%
   \ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \z@
    \thesection. \ %
   \fi
   ##1}}}
}
```

Comment: I suppose the error is due to missing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around your code. And you need to change `\@chapapp\ \thechapter` to `\@chapapp\ \oldstylenums{\thechapter}`.

Comment: Thank You!, the errors are gone once I've put the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. But now, how do change the code `\ifnum\c@secnumdepth > \m@ne` to make the number format as `\oldstylenums`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your full comment. The question is answered then. Thank You very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste portions of code from a package or class to patch them directly you need to enclose this parts in `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because `@` has a different catcode in user manuscripts than in class and style files.

Any case you can really shorten your attempt to the solution by canceling out part starting at `\def\sectionmark...` because you don't need to change it anyways. Then you simply need to replace `\@chapapp\ \thechapter` with `\@chapapp\ \oldstylenums\thechapter` to actually apply your patch.

It is possible even shorter: You can simplify the patch to

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifmainmatter\chaptername~\oldstylenums\thechapter.~\fi#1}}{}}%
```

placing it after `\pagestyle{headings}`. `\ifmainmatter` is an alias of `\if@mainmatter`:

```
\newif\ifmainmatter
\appto\mainmatter{\mainmattertrue}
\appto\backmatter{\mainmatterfalse}
\appto\appendix{\mainmatterfalse}
```

#### Complete example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifmainmatter
\appto\mainmatter{\mainmattertrue}
\appto\backmatter{\mainmatterfalse}
\appto\appendix{\mainmatterfalse}

\makeevenhead{headings}{}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase\leftmark}}{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifmainmatter\chaptername~\oldstylenums\thechapter.~\fi#1}}{}}%

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rendered]